# PHP proportional division

Tags: php, math, division

I'm trying to write some PHP, which will divide a number and have the last result be rounded down if odd. Therefore allowing an odd number to be proportioned.

For example:

5/3 equals 1.666 recurring. The code would produce an array of 1.67, 1.67 and 1.66.

6/2 equals 2. The code would produce an array of 2, 2, 2.

I've managed to come up with this:

```
$total = 7;
$divide = 3;

$array = array_fill(0, $total, round($total/$divide, 2));
if($total%$divide == 1) $array[count($array)-1] = $array[count($array)-1]-0.01;
```

I'm wondering if there is a more logical way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your array should have `$divide` number of elements.

So 6/2 would be 3 and 3.
I changed the `if` statement related to the remainder. I am just it to the last element.

```
function calculate($total, $divide) {

    $array = array_fill(0, $divide, round($total/$divide, 2));

    if($total%$divide > 0) {
        $array[count($array)-1] += $total - array_sum($array);
    }

    return $array;

}

$result = calculate(5, 3);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Ah yeah a typo there. Your method is a lot easier to read too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a collection of numbers which add up to $total? If so, I don't think your basic algorithm is correct. Consider 7/3. To two decimal places this is 2.33. Your code would produce an array of 2.33, 2.33 and 2.32, which together sum to 6.98, not 7.

Comment: Essentially, the last array value should be the left over after division. The code by @cornelb produces `Array ( [0] => 2.33 [1] => 2.33 [2] => 2.34 )` , which is correct.

Comment: Right. Although with this method, if $divide is large than the last array value could be quite a lot larger than all the rest. For example 7/21 will give 0.33 for the first 20 elements of the array and 0.40 for the last element.